# Border-spacing inside only

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to give space between the table-cell elements, but it also adds space on the sides of the table. How to remove that space on the sides? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLa6G/1/) . `<table>` tags can also be used for this, but the problem still stands

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="something-else">
        some other elements, table sides should align with this
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.something-else {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using a `table` for this?

Comment: Could use table also, but the problem will remain the same. If you know solution with a table, please share:)

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, it does not look like you are trying to render tabular data, but create a layout? If that is correct, I think all the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` stuff may be complicating the issue. Can you clarify (in a more general sense) what it is you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Try using div floats for layouts, that will give you more control and presentation across browsers that using table layout

Comment: @Kevin yes, im trying to create a layout here, but id like to be able to use it with different numbers of columns, that's why table is used.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you wanted.
Since you have wrapped everything as a table i used the idea of multiple tables and created a table around row 2 to make it

http://jsfiddle.net/GGnrM/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table2">
        <div class="something-else">
            some other elements, table sides should align with this
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.table2 {
    display: table;
    margin-top:5px;
    border-spacing: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.something-else {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding:1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific requirements, you could achieve the desired effect with `border-width` and `:first-child`:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    /* border-spacing: 15px 0;  -- Removed this */
    table-layout: fixed;  /* Added this (not required, but evened-out the column widths) */
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 15px;   /* Added this */
}
/* Added this */
.cell:first-child {
    border-width: 1px; /* Resets 15px border to 1px for first 'cell'  */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLa6G/6/